# Fast and efficent way to write large amount of data from DB to CSV file

Tags: c#, sql, database, csv

I'm creating a program who will fetch data from a DB and writes it to the disk using a CSV file, the main problem is that the DB can have more than 6 columns and more than 3000 rows.

I'm using [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to can write the CSV file from a string array.
I know this isn't the best method, so can you give me some **ideas** about a **fast** and **efficent** method to write the data to the CSV file without wating *+20 minutes*?

This is the code I've written who writes to the CSV file the data (*I feel that this isn't a good way to achieve this*)

```
// Start writing the CSV file
using (TextWriter _w  = new StreamWriter(String.Format("{0}{1}[{2}].csv", args[2], args[1], GetDateTime())))
using (CsvWriter  _csv = new CsvWriter(_w)) {
    _csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";

    // Writes the column names
    for (int i = 0; i < ODBCSQL.ColumnsCount; i++)
        _csv.WriteField(ODBCSQL.GetColumnName(i));

    // Starts writing the rows
    _csv.NextRecord();

    int _columnID = 0;
    int _cnt      = 0;

    while (_cnt < ODBCSQL.ElementsCount) {
        string[] _elements = ODBCSQL.GetElements(_columnID);

        _csv.WriteField(_elements[_cnt], true);

        if (_columnID == ODBCSQL.ColumnsCount - 1)
            _csv.NextRecord();

        if (_columnID != ODBCSQL.ColumnsCount - 1) {
            _columnID++;
        } else {
            _columnID = 0;
            _cnt++;
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("CSV Phase 1 : ok");

    _w.Flush();

    MessageBox.Show("CSV Phase 2 : ok");
}
```

P.S: The ODBCSQL class is only a helper class I've written.

*And below is the code of the ODBCSQL helper class*

```
#region [ODBC_SQL_HELPER_CLASS]
    public static class ODBCSQL {
        private static OdbcConnection _connection;
        private static OdbcDataReader _reader;
        private static string         _cmd;

        public static int             ColumnsCount  = 0;
        public static int             ElementsCount = 0;

        #region [CONNECTION]
        public static bool Connect(string ConnectionString, string Command) {
            _connection = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
            _cmd        = Command;

            try {
                _connection.Open();

                // Test to see if we can read data from the DB
                if (!ReadData())
                    return false;

                return true;
            } catch {
                CloseConnection();

                return false;
            }
        }

        // Dispose
        public static void CloseConnection() {
            try { _connection.Close(); } catch { }
        }
        #endregion

        #region [DATA]
        private static void ResetReader() {
            _reader.Close();
            _reader = (new OdbcCommand(_cmd, _connection)).ExecuteReader();
        }

        private static bool ReadData() {
            try {
                _reader = (new OdbcCommand(_cmd, _connection)).ExecuteReader();

                // Retrieve the number of columns
                ColumnsCount  = _reader.FieldCount;
                ElementsCount = GetElementsCount();

                return true;
            } catch {
                return false;
            }
        }
        private static int GetElementsCount() {
            int _cnt = 0;

            ResetReader();

            while (_reader.Read())
                _cnt++;

            return _cnt;
        }
        public static string GetColumnName(int ColumnID) {
            return _reader.GetName(ColumnID);
        }
        public static string[] GetElements(int ColumnID) {
            List<string> _elements = new List<string>();
            ResetReader();

            while (_reader.Read())
                _elements.Add(_reader[ColumnID].ToString());

            return _elements.ToArray();
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
```

Maybe the problem is the `ResetReader()`?

Comment: "DB can have more than 6 columns and more than 3000 rows" So little data shouldn´t take 20 minutes to copy. I doubt your problem is related to CVSHelper but somewhere different. Sounds like you should use a profiler in order to **measure** why your program is so slow. From the provided code it´s **impossible** to suggest a "faster" way.

Comment: _"P.S: The ODBCSQL class is only a helper class I've written"_ - then show it if it's relevant to the problem. You need to profile your code and identify the slow parts. There's no way this code takes 20 minutes, unless `_csv.NextRecord()` is writing to a floppy disk or something.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have update the question

Comment: NextRecord is still missing. Don't 'write handy wrappers around APIs if you don't know what you're doing. It's very likely that this static class of yours is causing the problems you describe. Create a new version of your code without this helper class.

Comment: @CodeCaster I've written this wrapper mostly to can retrieve the number of the elements in the column, I will try without the ResetReader, this is the only thing that I think can slow down everything, because re-read every time the entire DB columns.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Where? I don't close and re-open the connection, I only reset the reader to can re-read everything (and I think this is the "bad" part)

Comment: @HimBromBeere I need the `ResetReader` to can get the elements (data) from every column, because the reader is one-way. How I can achieve this without resetting him?

Comment: is `ElementsCount` the static method `GetElementsCount`?

Comment: @LONG I use `GetElementsCount` only one time to can save the number of elements in the public static `ElementsCount` variable, this to avoid to call the method every time. (If I understand well what are you asking)

Comment: Most databases have some sort of bulk export tool. Might be a better option.

Comment: @SteveJ Thank you for your response, but in this case I can't use this option.

Comment: Yes.  Use SQLCMD.exe which comes with SQL Server.  It is much faster than doing query from c#.  I often create a BAT file from c# and then run BAT as a Process.  See MSDN : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/overview-sql-tools?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You can write csv files by using SIS. Why are you developing it using c#?

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for the link, even if I have solved the problem the SQLCMD.exe is really interesting.

Comment: SQLCMD is designed to archive large databases.  It was taking me 45 minutes in c# to create my CSV, with SQLCMD is took only 5 minutes.

Comment: @jdweng Next time I will need to achieve something like that,  I will definitely try using SQLCMD, have you some timing tests already available to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved.

The problem was the `GetElements` function, I was calling it everytime in the CSV *writing loop*, which was iterating *again and again* all the "elements" (data) in the columns.

The solution:

```
public static List<string> GetAllElements() {
    List<string> _elements = new List<string>();
    ResetReader();

    while (_reader.Read()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
            _elements.Add(_reader[i].ToString());
    }

    return _elements;
}
```

I use this to retrieve **only one time** all the elements in the DB from the selected columns.

And this to write the file

```
// Start writing the CSV file
using (TextWriter _w   = new StreamWriter(String.Format("{0}\\{1}[{2}].csv", args[2], args[1], GetDateTime())))
using (CsvWriter  _csv = new CsvWriter(_w)) {
    _csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";

    // Writes the column names
    for (int i = 0; i < ODBCSQL.ColumnsCount; i++)
        _csv.WriteField(ODBCSQL.GetColumnName(i));
    _csv.NextRecord();

    // Starts writing the rows
    List<string> _elements = ODBCSQL.GetAllElements();
    for (int i = 0; i < (ODBCSQL.ElementsCount * ODBCSQL.ColumnsCount); i += ODBCSQL.ColumnsCount) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ODBCSQL.ColumnsCount; j++) {
            _csv.WriteField(_elements[i + j], true);

            if (j == ODBCSQL.ColumnsCount - 1)
                _csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
    _w.Flush();
}
```

Thanks to all for the helping!

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not a c# answer, but I would suggest doing that kind of work (mass data export/import) using ETL tools that are specifically designed to do that, specially if this type of request is not a one-time-off type of thing. Some example ETL tools are:

1. SQL Server Integration Services
2. Pentaho Data Integration

Comment: You are right, but the main reason why I'm "forced" to do this, is because I'm paid to do that type of program.
Anyway, I've found the problem and fixed, now writes 300.000 rows in some ms.